# How to learn to cook?

Tags: learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for a beginner learning to cook](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/resources-for-a-beginner-learning-to-cook)

What's a good way to learn cooking and avoid the current trend of my life that is best summarized by this xkcd comic: http://xkcd.com/854/ ?

Comment: I'd have chosen [How do we escape the cycle of bad college eating?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12218) as a duplicate instead; it even quotes this exact comic.

Answer (score 0):

1) Watch Good Eats.
2) Practice
3) Goto 1)

In order to learn how to cook one must practice. This is self evident.
But - what to cook and where to begin?

Well, I'd recommmend watching a few episodes of Good Eats (pick a few
episodes on food you enjoy). Pay notice not only to the steps he use, but
also his explanations on *why* he has chosen the various steps.

(Concrete suggestions: Episodes on eggs.

```
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=good+eats+eggs
```

)

The *why* is important, because in due time, you'll be able to modify
recipes based on previous experience.