# How to make plain white rice less boring?

Tags: rice, seasoning, budget-cooking

I'm a college student. I'm poor. Rice is cheap. Therefore, I eat a lot of plain white rice (medium grain).

I was wondering if there are any specifically tasty seasonings I could pick up that would make plain white rice a lot less boring.

Can anyone offer suggestions? I'm currently using *Chef Paul Prudhomme's Magic* brand seasonings, and they're great, but I would like to make my own seasoning. Is there anything else in particular that tastes great on white rice (preferably something I could make myself from simple ingredients)?

Comment: Nothing goes better with rice than beans. Canned beans are very inexpensive, and come in many varieties. They add a lot of flavor, and more importantly, boost the nutrition of your meal significantly, with protein, fiber, and other important nutrients. Ideally, sauté up some onions, peppers, or what-have-you; and toss in a drained, rinsed, can of beans — serve on top of your rice. However, a simple can of drained and rinsed beans will improve plain white rice a manifold. Beyond that: salt, pepper, garlic; a dash of cumin or a soupçon of curry. Experiment with other spices that interest you.

Comment: Olive oil, shallots &/or onions &/or garlic, fry a bit, pour in some wine, cover tightly, cook low, call it pilaf. You can add eggs on top in the last 10 minutes or so, add beans, add peas...and try barley instead of rice sometimes.

Comment: Have you considered eating more flavorful brown rice instead of white?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was asked before (although that one was closed, too).  Almost any herb blend works well with rice -- italian seasoning, za'atar blend, etc.  You can also throw in some bullion (chicken, beef, etc.) to make it more interesting.  Anyway, another question that may be of interest : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11075/67

Comment: Japanese people tend to eat their rice with furikake and/or tsukemono. Another common way is to combine with green tea along with the above mentioned flavorings to make chazuke. I would post links but I'm not too familiar with the UI on the mobile app. However you should be able to find Wikipedia entries for all the words.

Comment: Instead of simmering in plain water, try using store bought stock.  (Chicken, beef, or vegetable.  I have even used tomato juice, full strength or mixed with some water, or any liquid that you like.  A little (or big) dash of low sodium soy sauce doesn't hurt!

Comment: Dehydrated soup broths work well, as does a bit of ground meat or just a few veggies like fried onions or bean sprouts, which are inexpensive. Tomato is also a surprising match for rice, with or without other ingredients or seasonings. Using some mixed veggies, whisked egg and a few dashes of soya sauce make for a great fried rice. Go crazy, experiment. You'll be amazed how many combinations you can find that work.